# Creating a list of list

Tags: python

I have a text file which is shaped as follows:

```
0.6486020643999225      staunch wouldn  grew    even resisting
1.0     tinge loneliness        soon start      life life
0.6486020643999225      staunch wouldn  grew    resisting
1.0     pain    piercing        consciousness pain familiar except ten times attack
1.0     two ribs        developed       fissure
0.5073402520621506      mission freeing parents
1.0     my ribs developed       fissure
1.0     drive   wanted at_time  same night
1.0     heavy drifted sleep     fred    shoulder sleep baby
1.0     loneliness      start   life life
1.0     loneliness      soon start      new life life
1.0     pain    piercing        consciousness pain familiar except ten times raging attack
1.0     furious could break     two teeth
1.0     loneliness      start   new life life
0.8491130556422606      loneliness      attached        mission
```

I need to have an output as

```
[[0.6486020643999225,'staunch', 'wouldn',  'grew', 'even','resisting'],
 [1.0,     'tinge', 'loneliness' , 'soon',' start','life', 'life'],
 ...
]
```

The code that I have written is

```
res=[]
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    for i in f:
       #print(line)
        res.append(i)
user=[(i.strip()) for i in res]
print(user)
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
['0.6486020643999225      staunch wouldn  grew    even resisting', '1.0     tinge loneliness        soon start      life life', '0.6486020643999225      staunch wouldn  grew    resisting', '1.0     pain    piercing        consciousness pain familiar except ten times attack', '1.0     two ribs        developed       fissure', '0.5073402520621506      mission freeing parents', '1.0     my ribs developed       fissure', '1.0     drive   wanted at_time  same night', '1.0     heavy drifted sleep     fred    shoulder sleep baby', '1.0     loneliness      start   life life',....]
```

Comment: Are those *tab*-sparated lines perhaps? Use the `csv` module to read that into a list of lists.

Comment: It's hard to say excactly without knowning if that are tabs, but try `[ i.split() for i in res.split('\n') ]` on your data.

Comment: And are you sure you want *each word* as a separate element? I strongly suspect that some of those entries are word *groups*, only separated by a single space, while each column is separated by a tab.

Comment: @Adrija: also, you say you edited the post but that edit appears to have been lost when my edit was applied. Can you please verify that the information you meant to add is there?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes that was confusing to me as well. But then I reloaded, and your edits are visible now. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have tab-delimited columns, use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read that format:

```
import csv

with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    user = list(reader)
```

If the lines are not tab-separated but simply are space separated, you want to use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on each line (which splits on *runs of whitespace*):

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    user = [line.split() for line in f]
```

Note that this'll get you separate words even if the tab-delimited format would perhaps have given you word groups.

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have meant to use `[i.split() for i in res]`. While `strip` removes leading and trailing whitespace from a string, `split` separates it into separate tokens based on whitespace.

Still, a better option is to use something from either the `csv` library or from Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_table("myfile.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()`

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    print([i.split() for i in f])

[['0.6486020643999225', 'staunch', 'wouldn', 'grew', 'even', 'resisting'], ['1.0', 'tinge', 'loneliness', 'soon', 'start', 'life', 'life'], ['0.6486020643999225', 'staunch', 'wouldn', 'grew', 'resisting'], ['1.0', 'pain', 'piercing', 'consciousness', 'pain', 'familiar', 'except', 'ten', 'times', 'attack'], ['1.0', 'two', 'ribs', 'developed', 'fissure'], ['0.5073402520621506', 'mission', 'freeing', 'parents'], ['1.0', 'my', 'ribs', 'developed', 'fissure'], ['1.0', 'drive', 'wanted', 'at_time', 'same', 'night'], ['1.0', 'heavy', 'drifted', 'sleep', 'fred', 'shoulder', 'sleep', 'baby'], ['1.0', 'loneliness', 'start', 'life', 'life'], ['1.0', 'loneliness', 'soon', 'start', 'new', 'life', 'life'], ['1.0', 'pain', 'piercing', 'consciousness', 'pain', 'familiar', 'except', 'ten', 'times', 'raging', 'attack'], ['1.0', 'furious', 'could', 'break', 'two', 'teeth'], ['1.0', 'loneliness', 'start', 'new', 'life', 'life'], ['0.8491130556422606', 'loneliness', 'attached', 'mission']]
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters edited, please check, need you suggestions over this

Comment: Why readlines? you can just iterate over `f` directly. No need to waste memory on a list of lines you then replace with a list of lists.

Comment: Sir @MartijnPieters, let me try

Comment: If you want to keep it, that's your choice. You may want to explain why it works perhaps?